# Sampling performance profiler user interface to work with my custom domain specific language (DSL)

Tags: profiler, dsl

I have a custom Domain Specific Language (DSL) and a sampling performance profiler that generates a data feed similar to other profilers (current stack trace, inclusive samples, exclusive samples, etc). I am looking to leverage an existing GUI to better visualize the profiler results but haven't been able to find one that is pluggable/extendable in this way.

Also, the DSL runs in a computing cluster so any a GUI that can slice and dice data for a single node or multiple nodes at the same time is ideal. Eventually I would like to integrate it in visual studio but I'd be happy for anything at this point.  Thanks for your suggestions!

Rob

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you're going to find such a UI that you can leverage for your own purposes.

It shouldn't be too hard to write one though, not unlike the one in [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/),
or like this one that I did years ago, typically called a *butterfly view*, but for lines of code, not functions:

[image]

It's easy to program. You have some number of stack traces, and each stack trace consists of a sequence of lines of code, where each line of code represents a call to a function, except for the "bottom" line. Let's assume you have 100 stack traces.

At any point in time, you have a particular line of code which is the "focus", in this case `foo.cpp: 326`. The `33%` is the fraction of stack traces containing that line (even if the line appears more than once on some of the traces).
That percent is roughly how much overall time could be saved if that line could be removed, so that is what it is responsible for.

Of those 33 stack traces, it says line `gzorn.cpp: 99` appears above the focus line on 25 of them, and `foo.cpp:105` on 8 of them. (That's a case of recursion. Notice if there's recursion the ancestors or descendents don't have to add up to the same percent as the focus line.)

It also says of those 33 stack traces going through that line, on 16 of them `bar.cpp:45` is the next line down, 10 of them have `bar.cpp:10`, and 7 of them have `bar.cpp:17`.

Alternatively, you could show on each line the fraction of traces going through *that* line.

Then the user can hunt for costly lines of code by clicking on any one of those "neighbors" to change the focus.

Notice how easy this is to program. You don't need any data structure other than the stack traces themselves, and you don't have to calculate any statistics.
What's more you don't have to have a large number of stack traces, because all that would do is make the percents more precise, which is not particularly important.

P.S. I almost forgot to mention. Your stack traces should be taken not just during CPU time but also during I/O or other blocked time. That is critical, because often programs can be slow due to I/O, sleeps, resource waits, etc., and you need to know that. If you're worried about slowness simply due to competition with other processes, that's not really a problem because it does not throw off the percents very much.